# Using two individual check buttons in tkinter with the same value

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

In this code I'm trying to use these two checkbuttons, that should be active/inactive, completely independent of one another, but it doesn't work as expected:

```
from tkinter import * 

root = Tk()

enable = {'jack': 0, 'john': 0}

def actright(x):
    print(enable.get(x))

for machine in enable:
    l = Checkbutton(root, text=machine, variable=enable[machine], onvalue=1, offvalue=0,
                    command = lambda: actright(machine))
    l.pack(anchor = W)

root.mainloop()
```

When either "jack" or "john" is checked, they both activate/deactivate at the same time. I assume this is because they are initiated at the same value, but is there a way for them to be independent, but also still both be initiated at "0"?

Aside from my main question I do have a sub topic: Regardless of how many times the buttons are checked they still return "0", However the "onvalue" is set to 1 for the checkbutton, so shouldn't they alternate between returning 1 and 0 instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a dictionary with `IntVars` (or even the checkButtons) in it.
Then you need the usual `lambda machine=machine` (classic gotcha when initializing widgets in a loop).
So the result will be something like that:

```
from tkinter import * 

root = Tk()

enable = {'jack': 0, 'john': 0}
checkvalues = {}

def actright(x):
    print(x,  checkvalues[x].get())

for machine in enable:
    myvar = IntVar()
    myvar.set(enable[machine])
    checkvalues[machine] =myvar
    l = Checkbutton(root, text=machine, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, variable = myvar, 
                    command = lambda machine=machine: actright(machine))
    l.pack(anchor = W)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think you answered my question exactly, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Eric Levieil's excellent answer; if you'd like to print the binary only, be sure to define actright() without printing x, or you will end up printing the name in the dictionary associated with the value.

```
def actright(x):
    print(checkvalues[x].get())
```

(Note: not enough reputation to comment yet)